# Constraining user input to certain characters

Tags: c++, qt

How in qt constrain what can be typed in lineedit? I would i.e. want  user to enter just digits but not letters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the [setValidator](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qlineedit.html#setValidator) function and the [inputMask](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop) property. If you need something more complex than just numbers it is very easy to subclass [QValidator](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qvalidator.html) and use it.